# Layered or Virtual filesystem on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, container

I basically would like to do something like this: Let's imagine a utility called `layer`.

```
# sudo layer somefile apt install gcc
```

`layer` would launch apt in some sort of container. Apt would think it installs gcc on the actual filesystem but actually it is writing everything into `somefile`. `apt` still has access to the whole filesystem. So it's not like docker.

Then, I could do something like

```
# sudo layer somefile bash
bash# gcc -c foo.c
```

And `bash` would see `gcc` as installed by `apt` even though `gcc` was not actually installed on the system but was installed in `somefile`. Some form of container/jail but which would let access to the rest of the filesystem. My purpose is to create virtual environment for development without polluting my filesystem.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you know that you can mount as much of the host file-system, as you want, into a docker container? (containers don't have to have solid walls).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind some custom scripting, you can use [OverlayFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) (included in the Linux kernel since 2014).

OverlayFS layers two filesystem locations on top of each other: the overlay mountpoint shows everything from `lower`, unless it has been modified or shadowed by something in `upper`. All modifications done to the overlay mountpoint are recorded in `upper`; `lower` is never touched.
Additionally, OverlayFS requires a `work` directory that isn't clearly documented, but apparently serves as a temporary area before modifications are moved to `upper`.

Using this, you can create the kind of container you are looking for (see below for possible edge cases):

```
mkdir -p /var/tmp/myoverlay/{upper,work,mount}
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/,upperdir=/var/tmp/myoverlay/upper,workdir=/var/tmp/myoverlay/work overlayfs /var/tmp/myoverlay/mount
```

To "enter" the container, you can use the `chroot` ("change root directory") command to run a command (shell or other) inside your newly created `/var/tmp/myoverlay/mount`:

```
chroot /var/tmp/myoverlay/mount
# or
chroot /var/tmp/myoverlay/mount /usr/bin/apt moo # paths are relative to the new root directory
```

Note that this might not be enough for programs that try to access hardware devices, pseudo-terminals, processes, or system functions: those are provided by the kernel as special mountable filesystems — see the output from `mount` below:

```
proc on /proc type proc
sysfs on /sys type sysfs
udev on /dev type devtmpfs
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts
```

You can mount these into the overlay mountpoint (before entering it):

```
mount -t proc proc /var/tmp/myoverlay/mount/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /var/tmp/myoverlay/mount/sys
mount -t devtmpfs dev /var/tmp/myoverlay/mount/dev
mount -t devpts devpts /var/tmp/myoverlay/mount/dev/pts
```

Note that this will give your container more access to the system than you might like. Ultimately, you need to know your exact use case to decide whether an overlay filesystem is sufficiently separated from your normal system for that particular use case.

---

There can be an additional difficulty, depending on your filesystem layout: the `lower` directory is taken as is, without following any further filesystems mounted below it. If, for example, your `/home` is a separate filesystem, the OverlayFS will only show you the empty mountpoint at `/home`.

In those cases, you'll need to create separate overlays for each of these mountpoints, and then mount the additional overlays into the root overlay.
At that point, you're approaching the scenario where proper virtualisation is usually a more sensible choice.

Comment: If I combine this with `archivemount` I can probably achieve my original imaginary `layer` tool.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486916/overlayfs-inside-archivemount

Comment: Apparently, `mount --bind /dev/pts .env/mount/dev/pts` is a better way. At least it allow me to sudo once in the jail.

Comment: Also need to `sudo mount --bind /run .env/mount/run`. Network does not work othersize as `/etc/resolv.conf` is linked to a file in `/run`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `overlay` file system.

```
modprobe overlay
mkdir -p /path/data /path/work /path/mount
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/,upperdir=/path/data,workdir=/path/work /path/mount
```

Now you can `chroot` to `/path/mount` and see everything from your root directory, but changes will be written to `/path/data`. You can unmount `/path/mount` and remount it later with the same options.