# Overlayfs inside archivemount

Tags: linux, filesystems, overlayfs

I am trying to mount an overlayfs inside an archivemount (as a follow-up to [Layered or Virtual filesystem on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486810/layered-or-virtual-filesystem-on-linux)).

I am doing this:

```
mkdir -p {upper,work,mount}
tar zcf somefile upper/ work/ mount/
mkdir tmp
archivemount -o allow_root somefile tmp
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/,upperdir=tmp/upper,workdir=tmp/work overlayfs tmp/mount
```

Note that I allow root to access the mounted archive (had to update /etc/fuse.conf for that).
It fails with:

```
mount: tmp/mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlayfs, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

It works with the original folders. I checked and by default, `archivemount` is mounting in read/write by default. I also can write a file in every folder. I also checked the access rights and they seem to be correct. Root as access to mount and can write to it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you considered the fuse unionfs, then you don't need to be root.

Comment: Yes but overlayfs comes with your kernel. That's why I prefer that solution, unless I can't find a way around that read-only issue.

Comment: This question has changed from its original: It no-longer asks the same question. It should be rolled back, and a new question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual problem was that, by default, archivemount does not allow root to access the mounted filesystem. You have to add the `-o allow_root` option for that.

Note that you will have to update `/etc/fuse.conf` to allow that option.

Answer (score 0):

`unionfs` does a better job `unionfs-fuse $(pwd)/tmp/upper:$(pwd) $(pwd)/mount`. However the mount-point seems to have to be outside of the `archivemount` file-system.

I see no advantage of nesting the mount-point, and has the advantage of not needing root privileges (except to install), so this may be workable.

## Why

I have no idea why mount-point needs to be outside of the `archivemount`. If that is what the error is; I have little evidence to make a conclusion. I suspect that the mount point is the only file-access into the archivemount that is done as root, when using unionfs. Other file-access is probably done as you.

In the `mount -t overlay` case, where the upper-layer and work-area, can not be in the `archivemount`, it maybe because root has no access to this mount. Try:

```
archivemount somefile tmp
ls tmp/
sudo ls tmp/ #gets permission denied
```

Comment: You were right on `overlayfs`, I'll update the question.