# Virtual filesystem on Linux without root

Tags: linux, filesystems

What I want is something like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486810/layered-or-virtual-filesystem-on-linux?newreg=0206eb6775af4e6098dd85e85752d59b), but for non-root user.

I want my program to think that it writes to `/home/accounts` while in real it writes everything to `/home/myname/mytest`.

Note: that `/home/myname/mytest` does exist while `/home/accounts` doesn't.

And I want it for non-root user, i.e. without `sudo` or something.

Thank you!

Comment: If `accounts` does not exist, but the target directory does: why not just use a symbolic link? `ln -s /home/myname/mytest /home/accounts`. Use root once to create the link, as writing to `/home` is limited.

Comment: @Fiximan I thought about it, but I don't know how would it affect system. If I create symlink in `/home` directory would system think that it is a new user or something?

Comment: No, existence of a user is defined in `/etc/passwd` and is independent of having a directory in `/home`. As a matter of fact, you could make other directories the home of a user (as is done with `root` and `/root` or the system users). So no limitations or problems there (unless you try to create a user called `accounts`). Of course the user running the command must have proper permissions for the linked directory.

Comment: @Fiximan Thanks a lot! You can post answer if you want, I will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution seems to be creating a symbolic link with the respective name:

```
ln -s /home/myname/mytest /home/accounts
```

Of course there should not be an existing or future user called "`accounts`" that would have this as his home directory and whichever user is executing the command must have proper permissions regarding `/home/myname/mytest`. Note that usually `/home` has writing permission for `root` only, thus you will need `root`-rights for creating the link in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I tried with sudo. Thanks, it works!